# How to get id of selected row in autocomplete JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I would like to get the row id of selected item in my `autocomplete` function, I get the values of my source from a `php` variable.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [ <? php echo($toto); ?> ];
        $("#foo").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

I already tried this function but it does not seem to work. In fact, when I add it to my script, my `autocomplete` won't work anymore.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [ <? php echo($ListeNomsFormateeFinale); ?> ];
        $("#nomClient").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#textfield1").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                $("#textfield2").val(ui.item.value); // display selected id
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? and is there a quick fix to this problem?

**Edit:**

I  actualy needed to add a comma after `source: availableTags`, I also deleted the `return false`. but it dosen't return the id of the selected row, it actually writes the same value in the two textfields `textfield1` and `textfield2`

Comment: By the way, `echo` is not a function like `print`. Is `$toto` a comma separated value?

Comment: Can you post the values of `availableTags` variable which you get from PHP ?

Comment: Why you return false end of select function??

Comment: @MyWay yes, it is a comma seperated value, I made sure of that, And it displays all the values.

Comment: @alirezasafian even when I remove the return false it still won't work and won't display the values

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From : [Api Jquery UI - Autocomplete - option source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> 1. An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> 2. An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>      The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.

The second point (2.) give a way to store the "id" (or something else) of the selected object. By example :

```
var yourSource = [ { label: "Choice1", id: "id1" } ];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <input type="text" id="fooInput" />
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var yourSource = [
  {
    label: "A",
    id: "id1"
  }, 
  {
    label: "B",
    id: "id2"
  }];

  $("#fooInput").autocomplete({
    source: yourSource,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var e = ui.item;
      var result = "<p>label : " + e.label + " - id : " + e.id + "</p>";
      $("#result").append(result);
    }
  });
</script>
```

So try to format your data source like this : 
   `var source = [ {label:"Foo", id:"1"}, ... ];`

Comment: I changed the "value" in my source to "id" and it worked,  your answer helped me to get an idea of how the source works , accepted